A family of subsets $F$ of a universe $U$ such that the total intersection of all $W \subset U $ of size $k$ with $F$ is minimal.
Given a family of size $k$ subsets $\mathcal{F} $ of an finite universe $U$
and a subset $V \subseteq U $ we denote $$I(V,\mathcal{F}) = \sum_{X \in \mathcal{F}} |V \cap X| $$ 
We denote the $i$-th intersection number of $\mathcal{F}$ by $$ \max_{V \subset U, |V| = i}  I(V,\mathcal{F})$$
I am more specifically looking for lower bounds for the $i$-th intersection number for any family of size $k$ subsets of a given size, but any kind of references or names for this type of problem would be interesting.

For $x \in U$, let $m_x = |\{X \in \mathcal{F} : x \in X\}|$. Then $I(V, \mathcal F) = \sum_{x \in V} m_x$. Let $m_1$ be the largest value of $m_x$, $m_2$ the second largest, and so on. Then your $i$th intersection number is just $m_1 + m_2 + \cdots + m_i$. If $n = |U|$ is finite then
$$m_1 + \cdots + m_i \ge \frac{i}{n} \sum_{x \in U} m_x = \frac{i}{n}\sum_{X \in \mathcal{F}} |X|,$$
and this trivial lower bound can be attained if and only if we can arrange for all the multiplicities $m_x$ to be the same, which depends on your parameters.
